# Automate the extrapolation of the water level in QGIS using r.neigbour iteratively

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I wanted to do a post-processing of my model result (in my case water level). The workflow I want to do is as follows

Take water level raster (1m raster)
Use r.neighbour tool from Grass and extrapolate the water level and get the result and re-extrapolate it using the same algorithm, again do this process iteratively 50 to 100 times.

Doing this manually takes a lot of time and I have about 20 water level rasters to analyse.

Is there a way to automate this in QGIS Python or QGIS Model Builder?